# Change UITableViewCell's minus sign animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an issue with editing table view:

I changed the minus sign location in edit mode to the right side of the cell.
The problem is that the button is sliding from the left and it makes it looks weird.
Is there a way to change this animation?

Also, there is an animation when undoing the delete option (clicking the minus sign when the red delete button is displayed), any idea why?

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKqECITNnVE.) showing the issue:

---edit---
This is how I changed the position:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];


//Indent to the left instead of right
self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                    self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.width,
                                    self.contentView.frame.size.height);

if ((self.editing
    && ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
        && !(state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask))) ||
    ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask)
     && (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)))
{
    float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;

    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints - 35,
                                        self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,
                                        self.contentView.frame.size.height);
}

//Change editAccessoryView location
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0f];
//If can't use private classes (UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl..), use [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {


    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x = 10;
        subview.frame = newFrame;
    }
    else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x = 280;
        subview.frame = newFrame;

    }
    else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {
        CGRect newFrame = subview.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x = 200;
        subview.frame = newFrame;
    }
}
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)aState {
[super willTransitionToState:aState];
self.state = aState;
}
```

---edit2---
I identified that the part that causes the minus sign jumping issue is the
     //Change editAccessoryView location.
Without it there is no jumping but the minus button is back on the left side of the cell.
Any way around that?

Comment: How did you change the position?

Comment: Anything you do might be broken when they finally internationalize the table view cell. Maybe you can live with the default behavior?

Comment: My custom cell is designed to the right so the default behaviour does not suits my needs. Any safer way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like behavior and possibility to customize Cell controls have significantly changed in iOS11. I also had relocation of edit controls in my app, and now those appear in standard place, doesn't matter how I do layout :(
It still works ok in simulator on 10, but not on 11...

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but have you tried turning the view upside-down? You might be able to use a `UIView` `transform`.

(Code from the Internet, not sure how reliable it is)

```
CGAffineTransform rotateTransform;
rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI);
myView.transform = rotateTransform;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice idea, but the whole cell is upside down.

Comment: You should apply it to the delete control view, not the whole cell.

Comment: Oh, the problem is I'm using the default delete control not a custom one.

Comment: You're walking the view hierarchy in your own code, so you can get a reference to the delete control view there.